# coloured 3d models rendering issue while running on android

Tags: opengl, godot, rendertexture

I am using Godot 3.2.2 stable (GLES2) along with kenney 3d nature asset pack (glb) for prototyping a 3d game. Everything works just fine on my desktop computer, but when I deploy the game to my android device, the colours stop rendering correctly and show weird patterns instead of plain colours as on the picture (only for imported models, meshes created from Godot work just fine).

[image: texture artefacts]

It also seems that the sky is blending into the models like some sort of transparency.

Is that just a configuration issue? Or is there something I missed?

**Update 1**:
Another interesting information, the pattern does not move when the game is in motion, it just show on top of all imported objects but stay at the same position on the phone screen.

**Update 2**:
Here is how the models render in godot and the surface/materials configuration:

[image: bed object in godot]

And here is how the same object render once the game running on android:

[image: bed object on android]

Note that the floating platform has been imported in godot as an obj (not gltf) and is rendering correctly. the issue seems to be related to the GLTF format.

Comment: These patterns look a lot like z-fighting. Is it possible that you have two copies of these meshes placed in almost the same position, or that you're using a shadow casting light whose depth range is being stretched a bit too thin?

Comment: I double checked, and there is only a single copy of the mesh per items. I have just imported the glb and created an "inherited scene" from it.

Comment: I have experienced some issues with some cellphone models when rendering some materials. I believe it is related to the way they handle lights and transparency. I don't know how your materials are setup in the gltf, however, try the scene without lights (leave only the sky) and see if that changes anything.